# Mail Chimp & Rails Gibbon Gem - hostname does not match the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Just integrated the Gibbon, gem and I am getting a hostname does not match the server certificate error thrown back when trying to subscribe a new user?

```
    def subscribe_to_mailchimp testing=false
  return true if (Rails.env.test? && !testing)
  list_id = ENV['My-list-id']

  response = Rails.configuration.mailchimp.lists.subscribe({
    id: list_id,
    email: {email: email},
    double_optin: false,
  })
  response
end
```

Comment: Posting the stack trace from the error will help people figure out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slight change in the way that this works from the last time i looked seems to have fixed the issue.

Firstly

```
def subscribe_to_mailchimp testing=false
  return true if (Rails.env.test? && !testing)
  list_id = 'My-list-id'

  response = Rails.configuration.mailchimp.lists.subscribe({
    id: list_id,
    email: {email: email},
    double_optin: false,
  })
  response
end
```

Secondly

in config/initializers/mailchimp.rb

```
if Rails.env.test?
    Gibbon::Export.api_key = "fake"
    Gibbon::Export.throws_exceptions = false
end
Gibbon::API.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
Rails.configuration.mailchimp = Gibbon::API.new
```

Finally in application.rb

```
require 'openssl'
```

The Require openssl was what was generating the hostname does not match the server error as the call in the Gibbon app uses https

And if your interested in users.rb

```
def subscribe_to_mailchimp testing=false
  return true if (Rails.env.test? && !testing)
  list_id = "YOUR_LIST_ID"

  response = Rails.configuration.mailchimp.lists.subscribe({
    id: list_id,
    email: {email: email},
    double_optin: false,
  })
  response
end
```

Comment: same problem right here; can I ask you where you add the require "open-ssl" in application.rb ?

Comment: Yes add to application.rb at the top